# ODBC call stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, interbase

I'm trying to call a stored procedure but I'm not very know to the ASP.NET syntax.

The project uses:

- ASP.NET Core Web API
- ODBC connection
- no Entity Framework

```
OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(ConnectionString());
OdbcCommand ODBCCommand = new OdbcCommand("sp_insert_booking", connection);
ODBCCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
ODBCCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@project", "");

connection.Open();
ODBCCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Exception

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException
An exception of type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException' occurred in System.Data.Odbc.dll but was not handled in user code: 'ERROR [HY000] [ODBC InterBase Driver][InterBase]Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 1, char 0
sp_insert_booking'
```

My question is where to define/create `spInsertBooking` in the project structure.

Comment: A stored procedure resides in the database. Is your question related to creating or calling a stored procedure? If you want to call an existing one, the CommandText property should be the name of the stored procedure, in your case `OdbcCommand ODBCCommand = new OdbcCommand("spInsertBooking");`

Comment: What database are you using in the background? Why `ODBC` - seems quite legacy, typically not the best choice ...

Comment: I forgot the connection parameter in my previous comment, so it should be `OdbcCommand ODBCCommand = new OdbcCommand("spInsertBooking", connection);`

Comment: @marc_s InterBase

Comment: Please add the full exception details, but you probably need to open the connection, in the show code you don't do that. Add `connection.Open();` after declaring and instantiating the connection.

Comment: @Steeeve I updated the code in the question. Indeed I was missing the ```connection.Open();``` but now I get another exception. See updated question

Comment: What is `sp_insert_booking`? Your code doesn't match the exception message. Is the stored procedure in the database or not?

Comment: @Steeeve Sorry, the name of the stored procedure is ```sp_insert_booking``` and is stored in the database. I updated the code.

Comment: @JeroenR Can you post stored procedure sql script pls?

Comment: @Serge I can't share the stored procedure for the reason I'm sure If I'm allowed to share it.

Comment: @Serge are you familiar with this error: ```System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [HY000] [ODBC InterBase Driver]not yet implemented
```

Comment: @JeroenR The error is inside of the stored procedure. We can' t help you  if you don' t post it.

Comment: @Serge when running the stored procedure from within the database manager there are no problems. I doubt if it's in the stored procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using something like this:

```
OdbcCommand ODBCCommand = new OdbcCommand("EXECUTE PROCEDURE spInsertBooking", connection);
```

or the following, if the `spInsertBooking` command requires parameters:

```
OdbcCommand ODBCCommand = new OdbcCommand("EXECUTE PROCEDURE spInsertBooking 1001, 1002, 1003", connection);
```

(Items separated by commas; use single quotes to delimit strings.)

More info can be found in [the InterBase documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/InterBase/2020/en/EXECUTE_PROCEDURE_(Procedures)).